# Rendering salesforce lightning component into pdf (Generate PDF)

Tags: pdf, salesforce, lightning

I am working on a lightning component and within the components layout I have to provide a button which can generate pdf of that lightning component . I found some blogs but still not sure about the actual solution for this . Please let me know if you guys have some sample implementation example for doing this . 
Thanks !

Comment: There is no direct tag in lightning that will render the page as PDF. Why dont you use a VF page instead to render your page as PDF and call it from your lightning component.

Comment: I had almost same requirement as you,I could not find solution so what I did I created VF page render as pdf, onclick lightning us pass in the id to the url of the VF and it should get a pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the entire window, you can just open the print window then save as PDF (if the business requirement allows):

```
print : function (component, event, helper) {
    window.print();
}
```

If you want to print a portion of your lightning component, you might need to reconstruct the page to the pdf. Follow this:

```
var myWindow = window.open('','_blank', 'width=' + screen.availWidth + ',height=' + screen.avaliHeight);
myWindow.document.write('<html>HTML CODE HERE</html>');
myWindow.document.close();
myWindow.focus();
myWindow.print();
```

[image: Print Option Image]